# A student who has his own Careers 2.0 account

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, jobs

I've just received an invitation for Career 2.0 account, my question is that I am just student, how would Careers 2.0 help me? I don't have a job yet. I do not have any work experience most of my coding experience are from college and self enjoyment only.

What should I put on my Careers 2.0 account? providing that all I have as of now are collegiate projects and self made projects?

Comment: Any self-made projects that you're proud of can be displayed on your Careers 2.0 profile. There's also a section in your résumé for adding your education information as well.

Comment: in the self-made projects, I created several websites that I am very proud of, but most of them are for a collegiate project, I have not released them in public, is that counted?

Comment: Better prepare for your future. Show off the work you did, even if it's not public. It'll help you when you are ready for a job. You don't have to write everything at that time. Your profile would be ready :)

Comment: Not meant to offend, but who invited you? If it was an automatic invitation from the system, there seems to be a glitch in the code, I don't expect an account with no answers to match the intended criteria.

Comment: not this account my newest account got invited. I was gonna asked this question using that account but sadly there is an error upon logging in.

Comment: @Daniel you can get free entrt if you're active on GitHub/etc as well. I did :)

Comment: @user [Even I'm a student with a Careers profile!](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/manishg) _high fives_. My plan is just to keep it updated with my current projects and experience, and use it when I graduate. Or, if you have lots of time, see if you can use it to get a part time job (telecommute or something)

Comment: @Manishearth But does the system send out an automatic invitation if you're active on GitHub or similar and have an SO account? I don't expect (and wouldn't like) SE to track the GitHub/BitBucket/... activities of all registered users. For a GitHub based Careers account, isn't it so that you must make the first move?

Comment: @daniel hmm true..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Self made projects are a often a huge benefit when looking for a job, especially if you've shipped it and it's running live somewhere providing value to actual people.  Next to that is an open source repository, which offers the chance for the team who might be hiring you to get a glimpse at your coding style, proficiency with the languages used and thought process for how you solve problems.

In college I took a class on web development and it was a lot of fun because we didn't talk about servlets, rails or specific technologies for web development with the exception of introductory javascript.  We talked mostly about scaling, performance, style, monitoring and things like that.  Most of the class was spent working on a semester long project, which I ended up publishing in the end (www.rocketclubs.com).  I barely maintain it today, but in interviews for my first post college job, it was almost always the thing we spent the most amount of time discussing.  Those things really do have value.

The other main reason you should start a public developer profile now is because you don't want to be a data point when you go looking for jobs; you want to be a line. ([different context, but roughly same idea](http://www.bothsidesofthetable.com/2010/11/15/invest-in-lines-not-dots/))  Especially for someone coming fresh out of college, it can be difficult to judge how much passion and staying power someone has unless they have a visible record of accomplishments to reflect on.  If you start a profile now, and work on adding only 1 item to it every month, by the time you graduate you will have done much more than most fresh graduates... or at least it will look that way, and that will get your foot in a lot more doors than just drafting up a resume after you graduate.

---

EDIT: in response to your comment

Yes your collegiate projects have value when they are your most recent demonstrable experience, especially if you maintain them after the class.  It shows glimpses of your level of interest in what you choose to do and a work ethic most fresh graduates (undergrads anyway) have to convince employers of with their words only.

By adding 1 item per month, I mean read a technical book, critique blog posts which are interesting to you, commit to an open source project*, attend a meet up, publish an app and get people to use it, answer 25 questions on internet forums, get in a technical discussion on a tech news board, and the list goes on.  If you do only one of these things per month, within a year you'll have a decent history of public artifacts to share on your Careers profile.

Most places you'll interview at will start by asking you about yourself and the things they already know about you.  This is largely to help you calm down by talking about something familiar, but it's also to confirm you are capable of talking about something in depth.  By showing them your public artifacts before hand (by highlighting your Careers profile in your cover letter), you are giving them a list of starting points to skip a few levels deep into whichever topic they choose.  In this conversation, you will more quickly reach the point of showing them how you discovered non trivial solutions to the problems you have worked on.  That's something that is much harder to do without giving them this kind of in depth glimpse at what you know before hand.

Comment: How about Collegiate projects? I can say that my collegiate projects are great? and even though the semester is over I still keep improving should I also include in there? What do you mean 1 item a month? you mean like projects? is blogs or programming tutorials also considered there?

Comment: @user962206 I have edited the original response to reply to your comments.